# Why can't I extend a volume in Windows 8 disk manager?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I have this 40 GB volume (partition) that I would like to extend to 80 GB. I have already shrinken (downsized) the system partition in order to create some unallocated space before the partition that I want to make bigger.

[image: a]

The problem is when I right click on the 40 GB partition I can't select the "Extend volume" option. Why not? You can see by the screenshot above that the space before my partition is "RAW". That's because I formatted selecting any file system. But it was black before, indicating "unallocated" space, and I still couldn't extend my partition to include this space.

Let me guess... I have to have the unallocated space AFTER the partition I want to enlarge? I would like to try that of course, but there seems to be no option to move any partition or "volume" anywhere, not to a different disk nor left or right within a given space on the same partition. So how do you do it then?...

[image: b]

In the screenshot above you can see how it looks like with unallocated space before my partition. I obviously can't just remove my RECOVERY partition that sits right after my partition. I won't be able to restore the computer ever again. So that's not an option.

Comment: You tried a third party tool?

Comment: I'm not really supposed to install any applications on this computer. It's my work computer. So I would rather use built-in Windows tools if at all possible.

Comment: @user2806799 Can you suggest some third party tool? Preferrably one that's free and can be used without installing it?

Comment: I have used Easeus before, but I don't know if there are reliable portable versions of it.

Comment: [Extending Volumes Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/5377-extending-volumes-windows-8-a.html). Check out this article.

Comment: So either that or prep a Gparted disc then?...

Comment: @Sammy I find the built-in disk manager to be quite limited. If [GParted](http://gparted.org/index.php) is an option, I would use that instead, assuming you have a backup (just in case).

Comment: Yes, I do have a DVD reader in this computer. I find that Linux live systems on USB are just troublesome. And yes, that's why I use Acronis Disk Director on my private computers. But this is Windows 8? Come on? Surely, M$ must have improved essential tools like the disk manager (diskmgmt.msc)?... I know it looks old but they could have enhanced it under the bonnet.

Comment: @Sammy The problem is the partition comes *after* the unallocated space, and you would need to move it backward. Something which the Windows disk manager won't do. In fact, the program has mostly remained unchanged since the extend/shrink functions were first introduced in Windows Vista.

Comment: Now I remember why I ran away from Disk Manager and purchased Disk Director licenses for all my computers at home. So it is as I expected then. I started to realize this fact as I was typing the question. But I wasn't sure, i thought it had to do with the new Windows 8 or some other glitch in my system. So this is a built-in "glitch" from M$ then, eh?

Comment: Let me just point out that whenever you "shrink" a volume inside Disk Manager, let's say it's the system volume, the space that becomes unallocated is always put on the right side, i.e. the end of the volume you are shrinking. So even if I would **dare** to shrink down my RECOVERY partition, that new unallocated space, would not jump in between the RECOVERY and HEK partition, it would still be at the *end* of the RECOVERY partition, on the far right side. So... wouldn't it seem essential here then, to have some sort of option to move that stupid thing to the *beginning* i.e. left side?

Comment: Are there *morons* working at Microsoft or what?... Sorry, but I can't help it, I just don't get them at all... This is the latest version of Windows 8 on this computer but I have the same problem partitioning disks as I did several years before with previous Windows versions. Disk partitioning is kind of an essential function of any OS, it's not like I'm asking to much here... whatever... I'll try to get Gparted Live working today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that Windows does it's partitioning, you can only extend volumes forward, because the RAW space is technically *behind* the volume, it can not expand out backwards. You would need to use some 3rd party tool, or expand the **C:\** to take up the space allocated to it. It's just the way Windows operates. Booting from an external media, such as **USB** or **CD/DVD** will allow you to modify the HDD partitions and write the changes that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to use any tool to simply extend my C: partition as I had two recovery partitions in between my unused space and my C:.  I had to first move the two partitions that were in between my C: and unused space to the right-most edge of the unused partitions and then I was able to extend my C:.
I used the free version of EASEUS Partition Manager (http://www.partition-tool.com)

Comment: So what tool did you use then? I don't think you can "move" partitions with Disk Management, and that's the PITA.